# Firefox: button text does not respect padding when text is larger than button width

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue in Firefox 36.0.4. When button text is larger than the  button width with overflow property set to hidden, the text does not respect padding. I am not sure why it is happening and how to fix it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    button{
        padding-left:40px;
        width:60px;
        overflow: hidden;
        height:30px;
        white-space:nowrap;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">A very longggggg Name</button>
<button type="button">button</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how it looks like in firefox.

[image: This is how it looks like in firefox]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moazzam_khan/5e2q8thc/)

[Another fiddler that demonstrates the issue better](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/q50wqw2c/2/) by [Mr Lister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1016716/mr-lister)

Thanks

Comment: So you want the button to be expanded as per the width of the text like this http://jsfiddle.net/5e2q8thc/1/ ?

Comment: Or your question is about the padding ?

Comment: No, I just want the leaking text to be hidden as in the second button with text "button"

Comment: And you want padding on both sides ? You have mentioned padding only on the left.

Comment: I just added `padding-left` for explaining. I just want to understand why the `padding` or `padding-left` is not considered in first button example but works well in the second button.

Comment: I think the `padding` or` padding-left` is not considered in first button due to the `width` of the `button`. Provided width doesn't fits the `text` to be displayed inside the `button`.

Comment: @Amitsingh Second button text does not fit in the button area, but it is working well.

Comment: I think `white-space:nowrap;` is problem so remove that and add `float:left`, this is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5e2q8thc/2/

Comment: @Sathish S Thanks, but this is not the solution I am looking for, text in one line is important for me, so I used `white-space:nowrap`. `float:left` does not fix the problem.

Comment: The Question is:- As per w3c specification `width` property doesn't apply on `inline` element. Most browsers display button elements as `inline-block` because as per Specification given by w3c  `button` is `inline-block` element by default.  Since button are `replaced elements` that's why button always take width if using `display:inline;`.

Comment: see Demo. http://jsbin.com/nahepeqimi/1/edit

Comment: @KheemaPandey The buttons from my example are taking given width, but not considering the padding in firefox, in the situations specified in the question. If you inspect in developer tools you will see text is overlapping the padding area which should not happen.

Comment: Where do the specs say that overflowing text can not be visible in the padding?

Comment: why you are using fixed `width`?

Comment: @KheemaPandey I am showing a list of buttons in a grid, I need them to look alike in size, so I am using width.

Comment: @MrLister Sorry, I just assumed "text is overlapping the padding area which should not happen" from the chrome and IE. I am not sure about the stand of specs in this case. And I also want to understand the differences between the behaviour across browsers for this case.

Comment: It's strange though that the rightmost button does use the padding, even if that means the text it cut off to the right as well. Then what would the criterion be that FF uses. Also, the same thing does not occur when using divs with display:inline-block. Still, I don't know if you can call it a bug or just a design quirk.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, may be I should use a span or something else until the reason or a fix for this is found.

Comment: I don't know, but I made a new [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/q50wqw2c/2/) that demonstrates the issue better, as well as the differences between FF and other browsers. As for the solution, no idea. Use graphical buttons? Smaller font?

Comment: @MrLister Thanks, I added it to problem description. I will use span. These buttons are generated depending on user inputs. Creating graphics for that would be computationally expensive.